# Retrieve JSON file from the source and put it into the directory and make it updated periodically with PHP

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, caching

I'm using WordPress and use the API data with JSON format from a source for my site content, for example: http://api.source.com/data.json

But loading of my site take a bit longer because every time the page loaded will always take and read the file from the source, the question is how can I store the JSON file to WordPress directory and automatically update it every 12 hours?

Sorry for bad English but hope you got my point, Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options.

1. Use memcache -> Store the retreived json in memcache, and expire it after every 12 hours. This would be the fastest lookup.
   http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php
2. Database -> Store the retreived json in a database table with a key, you can use varchar , text , or blob datatype based on size of your json.
3. Write to a file -> Write the json to a text file in any of your directory which has write permissions,and read it from there.
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! I am interested in option number 1 but I was too dumb to understand and implement it. Can you give me an examples?

Comment: @Rifki , Examples are given in the link provided.